# I have rewrite dynamic url to seo friendly url but the old url also displays

Tags: .htaccess

Old url is `http://www.mhmn-test.com/dashboard.php?cat=home-construction`

My new url is `http://www.mhmn-test.com/list/home-construction`

I have used this htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^list/(.*)/(.*)/$ search.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^list/(.*)$ dashboard.php?cat=$1 [L]

#RewriteRule search.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 ^list/(.*)/(.*)/$ [L]
RewriteRule dashboard.php?cat=$1 ^list/(.*)$ [L]
```

I have want to display new url only

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 more rules to redirect old URL to new one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+list\.php\?cat=([^&]*)&subcat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ list/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ search.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dashboard\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ list/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^list/([^/]*)/?$ dashboard.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```